# What is the expected proportion of females in the total population of the society.

Tags: probability, expected-value

**Question**: In a society each couple can have at most two children. Each couple stops having a children once they have a son. What is the expected proportion of females in the total population of the society?

**My Attempt**: There are three favourable outcomes: M, FM, FF. Thus the proportions of females are respectively $1/3, 1/2$ and $3/4$ with probabilities $1/2, 1/4$ and $1/4$ respectively. Therefore I got the probability to be $(1/3 \times 1/2 + 1/2 \times 1/4+ 3/4\times 1/4)$. I am not sure whether this is correct. Also do we divide the expected number of females by the expected number of total to find the expected proportion or do we find the expected value of the proportions as I have done?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  Are we to imagine that Generation $1$ has exactly as many $F$ as $M$, that these pair up and the couple have kids according to the statistics you describe and then we compute the ratio of females to total?  That seems unlikely to me.  Are we instead to look at the ratio amongst the children alone?  Or are we to find an equilibrium figure so that these statistics are stable from generation to generation?

Comment: Should say:  I believe that all three of my questions have the answer $\frac 12$, though you seem to get a different result for the first question.  But that's because you  take proportions too early.  Supposing that there are $N$ families, compute the number of $F's$ and the total number of people.  You should get the ratio $\frac 12$.

Comment: You can't tell - not enough information, because you don't tell us the probability of having a boy or a girl (in real life these are not equal). However, assuming equal probablities, whatever the rules about not having more children, each child born is equally likely to be a boy or a girl, so there will be equal numbers of each (of the first children in families, half will be girls, of the second children for those families which have two or more, half will be girls etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can't weight proportions the way you did, because both numerators and denominators vary.

To solve the problem along the lines you suggested:

Assuming we are counting all the people in the family (including both the mother and the father) we see that there is a $\frac 12$ chance that the family has $3$ members and $1$ $F$, a $\frac 14$ chance that it has $4$ members and $2\,F's$ and a $\frac 14$ chance that it has $4$ members and $3\,F's$. Thus, if there are exactly $N$ families the total number of $F's$ is $$N\times \left( \frac 12+\frac 24+\frac 34\right)=\frac 74N$$ while the total number of people is $$N\times \left( \frac 32+\frac 44+\frac 44\right)=\frac {14}4N$$
So the desired ratio is $\boxed {\frac 12}$.

It's worth confirming that this is also the gender ratio amongst the kids alone, which implies that it is stable across generations.